# Transitioning opacity on an element with css drop-shadow filter

Tags: css, animation, safari, blur

I have an svg element with a drop-shadow css filter blur applied to it like so:

```
.my-svg {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) );
}

.active & {
  transision: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

When the containing div has the `active` class applied to it, the element fades in as expected, but when the transition time is over, the blur cuts back to be less... blurry. It's like the spread is increased during the transition. If I remove the transition it switches to what the element would look like in its final state after the transition animation completed.

What is it about transitioning opacity on an element with blur that causes the blur to be so much more pronounced until the animation is finished? It's not so bad on chrome but it's more pronounced on safari. It's really jarring. I've also tried keyframe animation for the opacity but the same thing still happens. It also doesn't affect `text-shadow`, only `filter: drop-shadow`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out how to get it to do what I want but I don't know why it works. Seems to work on chrome, ff and safari.

Using a keyframe animation AND a transition works. It doesn't work if you only use keyframes, and it doesn't work if you only use transitions. Here's the code that works:

```
.my-svg {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) );
}

.active & {
  animation: fadein 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I'm not going accept this answer because I think it still needs an explanation.